# Русский язык Нормы речи и грамматики

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Родители ,которые безгранично заботятся о младшем поколении, заслуживают уважения.  Вопрос: Есть ли в этом грамматические или речевые ошибки?Написал на сочинение на ЕГЭ)

Comment: Написал в сочинении на ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 2):

Родители, которые много заботятся о детях, заслуживают уважения.

Речевые ошибки:

1) Правильное деление на возрастные группы: родители - дети, старшее поколение - младшее поколение

2) "Безгранично" - это официально-торжественный стиль, не подходит к данной тематике.

Answer (score 0):

Возникшие вопросы типа "почему младшие поколения, если речь не идёт о старших?" и "почему заслуживают уважения, если этому поколению 2 года от роду?" может снять такая правка: Родители, которые безгранично заботятся о своих детях, заслуживают их любви. 
Подумал и добавил. Допускать, что они, любящие родители, заслуживают уважения сторонних людей, не следует, так как заботиться о детях есть норма.